# how to get top 10 sales price amount by Customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Customer Info table. In this table there are four fields. Customer comes in table two times but I want the total of the sales price for the Customer.

Sample data:

```
---------------------------------------------
| CustomerName   Amount  balance SalesPrice |
--------------------------------------------    
|  user1         300      300      200      |
--------------------------------------------
|  user2         300      300      200      |
--------------------------------------------
|  user3         b300     300      200      |
--------------------------------------------
|  user1         b300     300      200      |
--------------------------------------------
```

I want the output to be like

```
  ---------------------------------------------
  |CustomerName   Amount  balance  SalesPrice | 
  ---------------------------------------------       
  |  user1         300      300      400      |
  ---------------------------------------------
```

I don't want `user1` shown two times. I only want the total of the sales price. I have tried but I am getting `user1` twice in Customer name.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: now i am modified

Comment: The records for user1 are different, at first record Amount is 300 and in second one it's b300, How SQL should decide to choose one of them and omit the other?

Comment: user1  is same but it comes many times into table i want filter its once i  dont want its comes two times instead of that i want  i will calculate User1 sales price

Comment: you have to tell us the formula. Why is SalesPrice 400 but Balance still 300 ? How must the calculation be done ?

Comment: i don't care about now balance amount. i want total of sales Price for Customer i am trying to get user1 sales price

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a simple group by

```
select top 10
       CustomerName   
       Amount,
       Balance,
       TotalSalesPrice = sum(SalesPrice)
from   YourTable
where  CustomerName = 'user1'
group by CustomerName, Amount, Balance
order by TotalSalesPrice desc
```

This will get the sum of SalesPrice for every `user1` with the same value in `Amount` and `Balance` .  If that is not what you want then you will have to explain better and provide more sample data

Answer (score 0):

I think simple `DISTINCT` would work based on sample data :

```
select distinct t.CustomerName, t.Amount, t.balance, tt.SalesPrice 
from table t cross apply
     (select sum(t1.SalesPrice) as SalesPrice 
      from table t1
      where t1.CustomerName  = t.CustomerName 
     ) t1
where t.CustomerName = 'user1';
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

```
SELECT TOP 10 CustomerName   
    Amount as Amount,
    Balance as Balance,
    sum(SalesPrice) as SalesPrice
FROM Tablename
GROUP BY CustomerName, Amount, Balance
ORDER BY SalesPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select CustomerName, Amount, balance, total_SalesPrice 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CustomerName order by (select null)) as seqnum,
             sum(t.SalesPrice) over (partition by CustomerName) as total_SalesPrice
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Alternatively, If you don't care if `amount` and `balance` come from the same row:

```
select CustomerName, min(Amount) as Amount, min(balance as balance), sum(SalesPrice) as total_SalesPrice
from t
group by CustomerName;
```